# Issues with animations on android in react-native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm using the onScroll attribute of a ListView to change an animated.value based on the content offset of the ListView. This works perfectly fine on IOS but android freaks out. the updated positions are delayed by quite some time. Does anyone have any clue what might be going on? It's not an issue with the device itself because I've tested on multiple.

IOS: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nujcr.jpg
Android: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqGtK.jpg

Comment: Did you solve that issue?